Maui: floating tabbar on iPads in iOS 18
Ran our app on iPad in iOS 18 and Tabbar mysteriously moved to the top of the screen.
More info here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/elevating_your_ipad_app_with_a_tab_bar_and_sidebar

So in iOS 18 and on iPads only Apple changed the way Tabbar behaves and moved it to the top.
Does anyone know how to disable this in Maui and leave Tabbar at the bottom of the screen as it was for many years now?

Does this issue happen on the previous version of iPadOS?

No, iOS 17 places TabBar at the bottom. I did more digging and looks like Apple decided to move TabBar to the top of the screen inside NavigationBar. Very strange UI decision, it's now called "floating" TabBar.

Apple has changed the way that tabs look with iOS 18. This is not a .NET MAUI thing, but a iOS thing and not much we can do about it unfortunately.
There are some things we need to do to make it work correctly in all scenarios, that is tracked here.
In the meantime to revert back to the old behavior you can either build your app against Xcode 15, but that will only be a temporary solution as that won't be allowed into the App Store after April 2025.
The traitOverrides.horizontalSizeClass = .compact API seems to also revert the functionality back to the old behavior. Thanks @ErnestJ in the comments for the find.
To apply this to your .NET MAUI app you will need to create a custom renderer for Shell.
using CoreGraphics;
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Handlers.Compatibility;
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Platform.Compatibility;
using UIKit;

namespace OldTabBarBehavior;

public sealed class MyShellRenderer : ShellRenderer
{
    private sealed class MyShellTabBarAppearanceTracker : ShellTabBarAppearanceTracker
    {
        public override void SetAppearance(UITabBarController controller, ShellAppearance appearance)
        {
            base.SetAppearance(controller, appearance);

            controller.TraitOverrides.HorizontalSizeClass = UIUserInterfaceSizeClass.Compact;
        }
    }
    protected override IShellTabBarAppearanceTracker CreateTabBarAppearanceTracker() => new MyShellTabBarAppearanceTracker();
}

Then enable this renderer instead of the default by doing this in your MauiProgram.cs:
    var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
    builder
        .UseMauiApp<App>()
        #if IOS
        .ConfigureMauiHandlers(handlers =>
        {
            handlers.AddHandler<Shell, MyShellRenderer>();
        })
        #endif
        .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
        {
            fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
            fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
        });


Thank you. What about this?
if #available(iOS 18.0, *) && UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
traitOverrides.horizontalSizeClass = .compact
}
Found it in Apple forums, just don't know how to do this in Maui:
https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/756652?page=2

Well whaddayaknow, that works, thank you! Updated my answer on how to apply that to .NET MAUI today.

Worked great on iOS 18 but caused a black screen after the splash when running on an older iOS 15 device

If you have an app that has 5 or more tabs and you want them all to appear without a "More" option, don't use .compact use .unspecified for traitOverrides.horizontalSizeClass

If you want to display more than 4 tabs do not use:
traitOverrides.horizontalSizeClass = .compact
traitOverrides.horizontalSizeClass = UIUserInterfaceSizeClassCompact;

Instead use:
traitOverrides.horizontalSizeClass = .unspecified
traitOverrides.horizontalSizeClass = UIUserInterfaceSizeClassUnspecified;

.unspecified/UIUserInterfaceSizeClassUnspecified will restore the original functionality.
.compact/UIUserInterfaceSizeClassCompact will provide iPhone style functionality, maximum of 4 tabs with a more option.
